# ExtJS TreePanel - refresh and keep status of nodes

Tags: javascript, extjs, refresh, treepanel

How to refresh contents of TreePanel in extjs and save status of nodes (expanded/collapsed). When I do

```
fileList.root.reload();
```

All expanded nodes become collapsed. How can I avoid that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by manually saving tree state in array.

Comment: Could you kindly show us the code snippet for saving and restoring the tree state? I trying to do the same and no luck so far.